# The correct way of using "as"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is it grammatically correct to use the preposition "as" in a comparative manner?

For example:

I want the badges to be placed in the exact same position as in these images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your sentence is correct with your current usage of **as**.

In your sentence, it is a conjunction that indicates, by comparison, the way that something happens or is done.